# How to configure X-Ray for lambda service

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have number of Lambda functions written in JavaScript for node 8.10 deployed by Serverless framework.

When I go to X-Ray on web console I can't find any data, all tables are empty there. My functions use also SNS, Rekognition, S3.

I was under impression that Node.js functions are automatically handled by X-Ray.

Do I need to add something to my lambda functions to make them "discoverable" via X-Ray?

Comment: Did you activate it in your code? See: [Tracing AWS SDK Calls with the X-Ray SDK for Node.js - AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-awssdkclients.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to opt in with enabling "active tracing" for you Lambda function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-lambda.html